# A loop that I don't see

Tags: android, eclipse, android-alertdialog

I implemented an Alert Dialog but I have a problem. This dialog is repeated three times: When the app is started and two times when I start the game (after the use of the spinner and the intent). My request is that this Alert dialog has to show itself just one time (maybe when I open the game so after the intent) but it will good also if it will be opened at the beginning of the app. Thanks for all. Here there is my code:

```
Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.type, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s.setAdapter(adapter);

        scelta = flags;

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {
            scelta = flags;
   }

    });
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                scelta = pokemon;
}
        });

        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                scelta = smiles;
}
        });

        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

        button4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                scelta = MU;
}
        });
 s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(
        android.widget.AdapterView<?> arg0, 
   View arg1, int pos, long arg3){

   AlertDialog.Builder miaAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Manager.this);
   miaAlert.setTitle("Which is the difficulty?");

   miaAlert.setCancelable(false);
   miaAlert.setPositiveButton("Facile", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
           easy = 10;

                }
              });

   miaAlert.setNegativeButton("Difficile", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
             hard = -5; 
                }

              });
              AlertDialog alert = miaAlert.create();
              alert.show();

 //  ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01)).setSelection(0);
```

Hard and Easy are two int variables that I used to increment and decrement the possibilities of a player in the game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `s` is `R.id.Spinner01`, than

```
((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01)).setSelection(0);
```

is causing the loop that is causing your exception. You should avoit to call `setSelection` inside `onItemSelected`, because `setSelection` triggers `onItemSelected`

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. s is the Spinner. In particular =  Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01); What should I have to do?

Comment: comment that line out

Comment: Basically this Spinner is used to choose the level and start the application

Comment: you should not call setSelection inside onItemSelected, because setSelection triggers onItemSelected

Comment: No I comment out the line but the problem is still there

Comment: with the same stacktrace?

Comment: Yes, I comment out that line and I leave the code as you can see. I start again the game but there is a difference. I have the alert dialog two times instead of three

Comment: Ok I post the update where is the spinner and the dialog. In the other part of the code there isn't anything concerned this problem

Comment: are you calling setSelection somewhere else?

Comment: No. I don't call it anywhere more

Comment: No more setSelection in my code. I eliminate the only one I had

Comment: I am sorry... I have no clue

Comment: Ok I solve it. Basically some lines after the alert.show() I put an alert.cancel() so I close the alert dialog and bye bye. Thanks for helping me blackbelt